# It is possible to update or insert in place a HashMap inside another HashMap in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've just started with Rust. I have a HashMap that contains a string as a key and another HashMap as a value. I want to in place update the inner HashMap, which has a string as key and a i32 as value, if it has a specific key or insert the key value pair if the key doesn't exist.

My code looks like this:

```rust
let mut wp: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, i32>> = HashMap::new();


wp.entry(word)
    .and_modify(|map| {
        *map.entry(part)
            .and_modify(|count| *count += 1)
            .or_insert(1)
    })
    .or_insert(HashMap::from([(part, 1)]));
```

And I get the error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types expected `()`, found `i32`
```

which isn't very helpful. I have searched on google but didn't what I'm doing wrong. The diagnostic message looks like this:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:26:35
   |
26 |                 .and_modify(|map| *map.entry(part).and_modify(|count| *count += 1).or_insert(1))
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `i32`
```

I have been using a HashMap with a tuple as key and the i32 as value which is works but I find it hard to search after the first string in the key.

```rust
let mut wp: HashMap<(String, String), i32> = HashMap::new();

wp.entry((word, part))
    .and_modify(|count| *count += 1)
    .or_insert(1);
```

To me the `.and_modify(|count| *count += 1)` which works and the `.and_modify(|map| *map.entry(part).and_modify(|count| *count += 1).or_insert(1))` which doesn't look the same in principle.

Comment: That error usually means you can just `;` at the end, which ignores that return value, and it's happy, as in `|map| { *map.entry(...)....; }` You could also write a simple function that you could pass to `and_modify`.

Comment: `*wp.entry(word).or_default().entry(part).or_default() += 1` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:26:35
   |
26 |                 .and_modify(|map| *map.entry(part).and_modify(|count| *count += 1).or_insert(1))
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `i32`
```

Is saying that `HashMap<K, V>::and_modify` expects you to hand it a function whose return value is unit, but you returned `i32`. Just throw away the result and you'll be fine

```
wp.entry(word)
   .and_modify(|map| {
        *map.entry(part)
            .and_modify(|count| *count += 1)
            .or_insert(1);  // note the trailing semicolon
    })
```